# Multiple inheritance and unique_ptr destruction

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, vector, unique-ptr

I have the classic (possible problematic) multiple inheritance diamond scheme.

- B inherits A
- C inherits A
- D inherits C and B

I want to have a `std::vector` that can contain either `C` or `D`
objects so I make it as `std::vector<C>` which is `D`'s dad and it
works fine.

**BUT** when I use: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<C>>` then I have segmentation fault upon the destruction of the vector.

```
** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000009948018***
```

Why is there a difference? To me, even the first implementation is problematic.

**Code**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
};

class B : public virtual A
{
public:
    B() = default;
};

class C : public virtual A
{
public:
    C() = default;
};

class D : public B, public C
{
public:
    D() = default;
};


int main()
{
    { // this crashes
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<C>> v;
    std::unique_ptr<D> s1(new D());
    v.push_back(std::move(s1));
    std::unique_ptr<C> s2(new C());
    v.push_back(std::move(s2));
    }

    { // this is fine
    std::vector<C> v;
    D s1;
    v.push_back(s1);
    C s2;
    v.push_back(s2);
    }

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: "I want to have a `std::vector` that can contain either `C` or `D` objects so I make it as `std::vector<C>`" This might appear to work at first glance, but I don't think it will work in the way you expect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should declare your destructors as virtual. Otherwise, if your class `D` is deleted using a pointer to `C`, then the `~C()` destructor will be called and essential parts of the cleanup will be missed.

Also note that in your second part (not using the `unique_ptr`) you do some object slicing. It means you are creating a copy of `s1` of type `D` into a new object of class `C`, hence you can lose the extra information specific to `D`.

Here is the corrected code :

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    virtual ~A() {};
};

class B : public virtual A
{
public:
    B() = default;
    virtual ~B() {};
};

class C : public virtual A
{
public:
    C() = default;
    virtual ~C() {};
};

class D : public B, public C
{
public:
    D() = default;
    virtual ~D() {};
};


int main()
{
    { // this does not crashe anymore
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<C>> v;
        std::unique_ptr<D> s1(new D());
        v.push_back(std::move(s1));
        std::unique_ptr<C> s2(new C());
        v.push_back(std::move(s2));
    }

    { // this is fine because you slice D into C, still that fine ?
        std::vector<C> v;
        D s1;
        v.push_back(s1);
        C s2;
        v.push_back(s2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

### See also

- [When to use virtual destructors?](/q/461203)
- [What is object slicing?](/q/274626)

---

### Note

As stated in the comments, if you mark A destructor's as virtual, every derived class will also have a virtual destructor.
Writing it everywhere can make it more explicit. It is a matter of style.

Comment: Thanks @dkg. Do I need to declare it to all classes? It seems to be working only if I do it for ``C`` and ``D``. But why this is not a problem when I don't use ``unique_ptr``?

Comment: It is fine because you are doing a copy when you call the `push_back` method hence your vector will result in only C classes and your s1 of type D will destructed at the end of your little stack.

Comment: If you make `~C()` virtual, then `~D()` will also be virtual (but I find it helps to say so explicitly).  Then destructing through a pointer to `C` will call the virtual destructor.  If you delete a pointer to `A`, then `A`'s (non-virtual) destructor will be called.  Does that help?

Comment: @DimitrisDakopoulos see my update for your second part. You think it is fine, but you can add a method printing the name of the class and call it on your vector to see the behaviour of the object slicing, all will print what is defind in your C class, information in D class will be lost.

Comment: @DimitrisDakopoulos: you can only mark `~A()` as `virtual`, all inherited class would thus also have `virtual` destructor.

Comment: Summing up: use virtual destructors everywhere (@dkg). It is probably not the best practice (@TobySpeight) but it would work by just declaring the parent class dtor virtual (@Jarod42)

Comment: Standard advice is "declare a virtual destructor in any class intended to be used as a polymorphic base class".  A good rule of thumb (implemented by `gcc -Weffc++`) is that any class with virtual methods should have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 5):

Your "this is fine" example does slicing, the vector only contains instances of `C`, that's why it 'works' but does not do what you expected. The solution is as dkg points out is to use virtual dtors.